# anchor tag is not landing to its proper place in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used several ids on a page, So when you click on menu links, it goes to the pages. I am not able to add offset. It overlapping the content while scrolling. 
Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if(window.location.hash.length > 0) {
       window.scrollTo(0, $(window.location.hash).offset().top);
   }
});
```

Comment: Your code looks fine and should work if there's something overlapping it might be another issue?

Comment: can you show us the page and explain more the issue ?

Comment: Hi Temani, I need to share a link with you then, which I can't share publicly :( Is there any way can we discuss one on one?

Comment: @alpipego I agree with you mate, but that's what I am wondering why its not working